# Is a @Component contains other @Components which also contain @Components a bad idea in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, components, autowired

Think of this scenario. I have a component that @Autowired another component that also @Autowired another component.

Animal.java

```
@Component
public class Animal{
   @Autowired
   private Dog dog;
...
}
```

Dog.java

```
@Componet
public class Dog{
   @Autowired
   private Fight fight;
....
}
```

Fight.java

```
@Component
public class Fight{
....
}
```

Let us say the depth of the @Component Animal is 3. Imagine this depth is 10. Would this be pretty bad? How to avoid this?

---Edit in April 18th---- 
Thanks for the below replies. I agree that there is nothing for these codes. Just make ppl feel a big headache. The real scenario is that components do not have a strong relationship and the complexity is much higher than my example, so using interface might be hard. Is there a better way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but in your case I think you need to use an interface and then you can inject the `Fight` object using the constructor.

For example:

```
public interface Animal {
    private Fight fight;
}
```

Then you should implement each animal, like this:

```
public Dog implements Animal {

   public Dog() { }

   @Autowired
   public Dog(Fight fight) {
       this.fight = fight;
   }
}

public Cat implements Animal {

   public Cat() { }

   @Autowired
   public Cat(Fight fight) {
       this.fight = fight;
   }
}
```

You don't need to use an explicit `@Autowired`. You can declare the property using `final` keyword. For example:

```
@Component
public class Animal{

  private final Dog dog;

}
```

Comment: The question doesn't suggest any inheritance relationship between Dog and Animal.

Comment: @tgdavies I know, but it's never too late to give a tip to enhance others' code. Always do much more than asked.

Comment: It's not an enhancement. You're changing the semantics of their code.

Comment: @tgdavies IMHO, changing the semantics can be in fact enhancements. These abstract talks lead to nowhere.

Comment: The OP might make the mistake of believing that the code in your answer is equivalent to theirs. (And by the way "...and then..." makes it sound as though using an interface is somehow a prerequisite for constructor injection)

Comment: @shimatai Thanks for your reply. Using interface can help in some way for sure. But the real scenario is that the legacy code I am facing does not have a strong inheritance relationship and the depth make it difficult to reorg.

Answer (score 0):

it's not wrong. but you're better making animal an interface then autowire other services. also sidenote, it would be better if you define exactly what that component is rather then sayin @Component. for example if fight is a service use @Service.